# Duplicating rows based on column value using SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

Using SQLite, I need to transform an input file into an output file wherein rows should be duplicated based on the value in count column.

The format of the table is as follows:

```
# creating input database
input_file = """
    CREATE TABLE input_file (
      dateid date NOT NULL ,
      groupid NOT NULL,
      result INT NOT NULL,
      result_count INT NOT NULL
    ) 
    """
# fresh table
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS input_file")
cursor.execute(input_file)
```

I'm fairly new to SQL so I'm needing help with what codes to use. Below is the before and after I'm looking at

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT dateid, groupid, result, result_count, 1 counter
  FROM input_file
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dateid, groupid, result, result_count, counter + 1
  FROM cte 
  WHERE counter < result_count
)
SELECT dateid, groupid, result
FROM cte
```

If you want to insert these rows in another table, first create it:

```
CREATE TABLE output_file (
      dateid date NOT NULL ,
      groupid NOT NULL,
      result INT NOT NULL
    )
```

and then insert the rows:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT dateid, groupid, result, result_count, 1 counter
  FROM input_file
  UNION ALL
  SELECT dateid, groupid, result, result_count, counter + 1
  FROM cte 
  WHERE counter < result_count
)
INSERT INTO output_file(dateid, groupid, result)
SELECT dateid, groupid, result
FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7c75c24b27746774b553bea4ad3a8c77).

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the rows that are output when you do a SELECT, if you join with another table that has multiple matching rows.  This will only be practical if the count is relatively small.  Create a new table with a `repeat_count` column that has 1 `1`, 2 `2`, 3 `3` etc.  Then you can:

```
SELECT * FROM input_file JOIN repeats ON result_count = repeat_count
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've edited my question for further information. What do you mean by having another table with multiple matching rows?

Comment: @Lara sorry if my explanation wasn't clear.  I meant a table containing one row having a value of `1`, two rows containing a value of `2`, etc.  I can see now with the edit you made that my method won't be practical for you.

Comment: oh okay got it. Yes, might not be feasible if I have large duplication value requirements. Thank you though! :)